# Getting 406 on IE after Google redirects my site

Tags: seo, htaccess, wordpress, apache, internet-explorer

I have a WordPress blog. When I search the posts from my site in Google, the results appear and on clicking the result I can open that particular post on my site.
But while doing the same on `Internet Explorer`, I get a 406 error, but on refreshing the page, the site opens. Its kind of weird. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Do you have mod_security enabled for Apache? If so, you could try disabling that and see if that changes anything. 406 errors are quite often caused by mod_security. Not sure why only IE would trigger it though, maybe you have a strange user-agent being set for some reason?

Comment: I think its not with mod_security... tried that too. The site opens quite good, the issue is only when google search redirects from its result to the main site on IE

Comment: Any strange extensions added to IE that may be affecting the headers your browser sends? Something possibly that's trying to intercept search queries or something?

Comment: no.. checked... not working

Comment: Does your site act differently towards internet explorer? For example, do you have lines in .htaccess or other server or website config files that mention internet explorer?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a possible cause can be you have two conflicting MIME types. Here is a solution provided by Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942050